# Angularjs currency formatting in input box

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi! I have the following input box :

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items"
    <input ng-model="item.cost" />
</div>
```

I am trying to figure out how to apply "currency" filter to the input box. So that when value is displayed it displays with $ sign and proper currency notations. I can do with span using `{{item.cost | currency }}` but I need the box to be editable to change the value if needed. 
Please let me know how I can apply currency filter to the input box.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
.directive('currencyFormatter', ['$filter', function ($filter) {


            formatter = function (num) {
              return $filter('currency')(num);
            };

        return {
          restrict: 'A',
          require: 'ngModel',
          link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$parsers.push(function (str) {
             return str ? Number(str) : '';
            });
            ngModel.$formatters.push(formatter);

            element.bind('blur', function() {
              element.val(formatter(ngModel.$modelValue))
            });
            element.bind('focus', function () {
              element.val(ngModel.$modelValue);
            });
          }
        };
      }]);
```

And the html

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input ng-model="item.cost" currency-formatter/>
  </div>
 <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{item.cost}}
  </div>
```

Comment: Tried this, attaching the directive to the module containing the controller I want to use it in.  Did not work, does not appear to eve be called